Почему не работает прерывание USART1 в STM32F100BRT6B
Есть простой код, где внешнее прерывание от кнопки отправляет «1» через USART1, и при поступлении нуля с того же UART светодиоды гаснут. Для компиляции я использую KEIL 5.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stm32f10x.h>
#include <system_stm32f10x.h>


#define BLUE_LED_ON GPIOC->BSRR=GPIO_BSRR_BS8
#define GREEN_LED_ON GPIOC->BSRR=GPIO_BSRR_BS9
#define BLUE_LED_OFF GPIOC->BSRR=GPIO_BSRR_BR8
#define GREEN_LED_OFF GPIOC->BSRR=GPIO_BSRR_BR9

void EXTI0_IRQHandler (void);
void USART1_IRQHandler (void);
void Button_Interrupt_Init (void);
void Led_Init (void);
void UART_Init (void);

void UART_Send_Str (char*StrToSend);    

char SendStr[] = "asdgasdfgadfg\t";

int main (void)
{//USART1 TX-PA9 RX-PA10
    SystemInit();
    Button_Interrupt_Init();
    UART_Init();
    Led_Init();
    GREEN_LED_ON;
    BLUE_LED_ON;
    
    while(1){}
}

void Button_Interrupt_Init (void)
{
    RCC->APB2ENR |= RCC_APB2ENR_AFIOEN;
    AFIO->EXTICR[0] |= AFIO_EXTICR1_EXTI0_PA;
    RCC->APB2ENR |= RCC_APB2ENR_IOPAEN;
    
    __enable_irq();
    EXTI->PR |= EXTI_PR_PR0;
    EXTI->RTSR |= EXTI_RTSR_TR0;
    EXTI->IMR |= EXTI_IMR_MR0;
    NVIC_EnableIRQ(EXTI0_IRQn); 
}
void Led_Init (void)
{
    RCC->APB2ENR |= RCC_APB2ENR_IOPCEN;
    GPIOC->CRH = GPIO_CRH_MODE8|GPIO_CRH_MODE9;
    BLUE_LED_ON;
    GREEN_LED_ON;
    //for (int i =0; i<300000; i++);
    BLUE_LED_OFF;
    GREEN_LED_OFF;
    //for (int i =0; i<300000; i++);
    BLUE_LED_ON;
    GREEN_LED_ON;
    //for (int i =0; i<300000; i++);
    BLUE_LED_OFF;
    GREEN_LED_OFF;
    //for (int i =0; i<300000; i++);
    BLUE_LED_ON;
    GREEN_LED_ON;
    //for (int i =0; i<300000; i++);
    BLUE_LED_OFF;
    GREEN_LED_OFF;
    //for (int i =0; i<300000; i++);
}
void UART_Init (void)
{
    GPIOA->CRH &= ~(GPIO_CRH_CNF9|GPIO_CRH_CNF10|GPIO_CRH_MODE9|GPIO_CRH_MODE10);
    GPIOA->CRH |= GPIO_CRH_MODE9_0|GPIO_CRH_CNF9_1|GPIO_CRH_MODE10_0|GPIO_CRH_CNF10_1;
    
    RCC->APB2ENR |= RCC_APB2ENR_USART1EN;
    USART1->BRR = 0x4E2;
    USART1->CR1 |= USART_CR1_RXNEIE|USART_CR1_TE|USART_CR1_RE;
    USART1->CR1 &= ~(USART_CR1_M|USART_CR1_PCE);
    USART1->CR2 &= ~(USART_CR2_STOP);
    NVIC_EnableIRQ(USART1_IRQn);
    USART1->CR1 |= USART_CR1_UE;
}   
void USART1_IRQHandler (void)
{
    if(USART1->SR & USART_SR_RXNE)                                                                                                                              // Check is 'RX not empty' bit set -> data is in UART->DR
    {
        uint8_t RXc = (uint8_t)(USART1->DR&0xFF);                                                                   // put symbol from UART->DR in RXc variable
        switch(RXc)                                                                                                                                                             // Symbol-dependent cases
        {
            case '0':
                GREEN_LED_OFF;
            break;
            case '1':
                BLUE_LED_OFF;
            break;
            default:
                GREEN_LED_ON;
                BLUE_LED_ON;
            break;
        }
    }
    NVIC_ClearPendingIRQ(USART1_IRQn);                                                                                                                  // Clear pending bit from UART1 interrupt
}

void EXTI0_IRQHandler (void)
{
    //USART1->DR = 0xDB;    
    UART_Send_Str(SendStr);
    EXTI->PR |= EXTI_PR_PR0;
}

void UART_Send_Str (char* StrToSend)
{
    while (*StrToSend)
    {
        USART1->DR = *StrToSend++;
        while (!(USART1->SR&USART_SR_TC)){}
    }
}


Проблема в том, что при нажатии кнопки на терминал приходит "1" и всё ок, но когда я пытаюсь отправить символ с терминала на микроконтроллер, то MCU ни при каких обстоятельствах не входит в прерывание. GREEN_LED_ON и BLUE_LED_ON должны быть включены, когда MCU входит в прерывание, но ничего не происходит.
Я попытался создать проект STM32CUBEIDE с инициализацией USART1, добавив в автоматически сгенерированный код функции UART_Init (то же самое, что и выше, но без конфигураций контактов) и USART1_IRQHandler. Код CUBEIDE (без «начала/конца пользовательского кода и т. д.»):
#include "main.h"

#define BLUE_LED_ON GPIOC->BSRR=GPIO_BSRR_BS8
#define GREEN_LED_ON GPIOC->BSRR=GPIO_BSRR_BS9
#define BLUE_LED_OFF GPIOC->BSRR=GPIO_BSRR_BR8
#define GREEN_LED_OFF GPIOC->BSRR=GPIO_BSRR_BR9

UART_HandleTypeDef huart1;

void UART_Init (void);
void USART1_IRQHandler (void);

void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void);

int main(void)
{


  HAL_Init();


  SystemClock_Config();


  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_USART1_UART_Init();

  UART_Init();
  GREEN_LED_ON;
  BLUE_LED_ON;



  while (1)
  {

  }

}


void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

 
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEState = RCC_HSE_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEPredivValue = RCC_HSE_PREDIV_DIV1;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLMUL = RCC_PLL_MUL3;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

 
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_0) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}


static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void)
{


  huart1.Instance = USART1;
  huart1.Init.BaudRate = 115200;
  huart1.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart1.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart1.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart1.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart1.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart1.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}


static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};
  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOD_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();
  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_8|GPIO_PIN_9, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
  /*Configure GPIO pins : PC8 PC9 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_8|GPIO_PIN_9;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStruct);
}
void UART_Init (void)
{
    USART1->CR1 |= USART_CR1_RXNEIE|USART_CR1_TE|USART_CR1_RE;
    USART1->CR1 &= ~(USART_CR1_M|USART_CR1_PCE);
    USART1->CR2 &= ~(USART_CR2_STOP);
    NVIC_EnableIRQ(USART1_IRQn);
    USART1->CR1 |= USART_CR1_UE;
}
void USART1_IRQHandler (void)
{
    if(USART1->SR & USART_SR_RXNE)                                                                                                                              // Check is 'RX not empty' bit set -> data is in UART->DR
    {
        uint8_t RXc = (uint8_t)(USART1->DR&0xFF);                                                                   // put symbol from UART->DR in RXc variable
        switch(RXc)                                                                                                                                                             // Symbol-dependent cases
        {
            case '0':
                GREEN_LED_OFF;
            break;
            case '1':
                BLUE_LED_OFF;
            break;
            default:
                BLUE_LED_ON;
                GREEN_LED_ON;
            break;
        }
    }
    NVIC_ClearPendingIRQ(USART1_IRQn);                                                                                                                  // Clear pending bit from UART1 interrupt
}

void Error_Handler(void)
{
  __disable_irq();
  while (1)
  {
  }
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */

И этот код отлично работает! Я получаю все сообщения от терминала и контроллер обрабатывает их так, как нужно
Единственное отличие этих кодов, которое я заметил, это отсутствие инициализации контактов PA9 и PA10 (отвечающих за USART) в коде CUBE.
Вопросы следующие:

В чем может быть проблема с кодом KEIL? (думаю, что-то связанное с конфигурацией USART-контактов)
Есть ли конфигурация контактов USART (PA9/PA10) в коде CUBE? Где HAL выполняет эту настройку?

Спасибо!
